# Returning earliest record in a group

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select drl.id, drl.ap, drl.sqn, drl.date 
from srs_drl drl
```

this will out output something like this:

```
14000001  01  01  05/11/2015
14000001  01  01  06/11/2015
14000001  01  01  01/12/2015
14000001  01  01  04/01/2016
15000234  01  02  05/11/2015
15000234  01  03  06/11/2015
15000234  01  03  01/12/2015
15000234  01  04  04/01/2016
```

For every unique first 3 columns I need to retrieve the earliest date. So for the above table I wish to return:

```
14000001  01  01  05/11/2015
15000234  01  02  05/11/2015
15000234  01  03  06/11/2015
15000234  01  04  04/01/2016
```

Any help with this query would be much appreciated. I've tried using TOP but that only returns the first record for the entire table rather than the first record grouped by the first 3 columns.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY` combined with `MIN`:

```
Select drl.id, drl.ap, drl.sqn, MIN(drl.date)
from srs_drl drl
group by drl.id, drl.ap, drl.sqn
```

Alternatively, a `NOT EXISTS` to return a row if no one with same drl.id, drl.ap, drl.sqn is even earlier:

```
Select drl.id, drl.ap, drl.sqn, drl.date
from srs_drl drl
where not exist (select 1 from from srs_drl d2
                 where d2.id = drl.id
                   and d2.ap = drl.ap
                   and d2.sqn = drl.sqn 
                   and d2.date < drl.date)
```

Note that date is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, so you may need to write `"date"`.

Comment: Or wrap `date` in square brackets -- `drl.[date]`

Comment: Those d*mn square brackets... Yes, they work as well.

Comment: Thanks jarlh!I used the GROUP BY and it worked a treat. Thanks very much, in essence it was quite an easy problem to solve, I was just having a real mental blank - didn't help it was 16:45 at the end of a long day at work.